# How to set hex color code to `tbody-tr-class` ? (bootstrap-vue)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to set `b-table` row with different colors. bootstrap-vue have a class `tbody-tr-class`.

```
<b-table
          head-variant="light"
          :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"
          :items="Clients"
          :fields="headers"
 >
```

Now, the class return some custom color assigned with hex color code.

```
rowClass(item, type) {
      if (!item || type !== "row") return;
      if (item.color_id === 1) return "table-hexvalue1";
      else return "table-hexvalue2";
    },
```

I have tryied to assign class like these:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.hexvalue1 {
background-color: #D9FFBC;
color: #D9FFBC;
}
.hexvalue2 {
background-color: #fd7e14;
color: #fd7e14;
}
</style>
```

It's not working! How to set hex color code to `tbody-tr-class`?

Answer (score 0):

Give spacing for your class Names like

```
rowClass(item, type) {
      if (!item || type !== "row") return;
      if (item.color_id === 1) return "table hexvalue1";
      else return "table hexvalue2";
    },
```

since you have specified stylings only for `.hexvalue1` and `.hexvalue2`

Answer (score -1):

I think use [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```js
      computed: {
        rowClass(item, type) {
          if (!item || type !== "row") {
            return "";
          }
          if (item.color_id === 1) {
            return "table-hexvalue1";
          } else {
            return "table-hexvalue2";
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: 'rowClass' is placed inside methods. It does not work in computed property.

Comment: Remove ```rowClass()``` from methods, Then place in computed.

Comment: Or you can use ```beforMounted ``` to call your ```rowClass()```